# Filtering content from df output

Tags: awk, grep

I have the command below to get the filesystem usage on a server:

```
df -k | awk '{print $5 " " $6}' | grep %
```

**When executed, the following are the results:**

```
97% /
0% /proc
0% /etc/mnttab
0% /dev/fd
46% /var
1% /var/run
1% /tmp
54% /opt/app/oracle
22% /opt/app/proviso
```

My question is how can I make the line containing `97% /` disappear?

Comment: It's really hard to read black text on a blue background.  Can you just write that output in as text and indicate verbally which entry you want to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

You can do both the filtering and pruning with `awk`:

```
df -k | awk '/%/ && NR > 2 {print $5 " " $6}'
```

`/%/` does the same job as `grep %`.

`NR > 2` filter out the label and `/` lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first line with tail:

```
df -k | awk '{print $5 " " $6}' | grep % | tail --lines +2
```

`+2` means you want to print all lines starting with line 2.

Comment: Hi, In relation to what I have posted. Allow me to explain my side a bit why I posted this question. Actually I'm currently attending a unix boot camp this was actually a homework.

Comment: Actually I didn't get it correctly. Here's our trainer's response:

Comment: You are missing  the assumption I mentioned:

the position of it in the list might also change(assumption but not necessarily true)  so it can be in the first line, second line or last line or anywhere in the list.

Comment: @JPenaranda I think that user1700494 gives you the answer your trainer waited: the suppression of line containing only `/` as 6th field thanks to a regular expression.

Comment: I strongly doubt the `/` entry can be anywhere but the first directory displayed by `df`, given the fact it is the first one mounted by the OS by design and the root of the remaining mounted file systems hierarchy. On the other hand, user1700494's recommendation of using the `-P` flag is very valid.

Answer (score 0):

You will be fine until `df` returns you something like this:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg-lv_root
                  367G  246G  103G  71% /
tmpfs                  48G     0   48G   0% /dev/shm
```

This will obviously broke your script/command. So i recommend you to **always apply `-P` key to `df` command in your scripts**.
Regarding your intial question, i'd do this with simple regex

```
df -Ph  |awk '{if($6 ~ /^\/.+/) print $5, $6}'
```